# How to apply captcha only on certain action in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a model with a captcha. I can create new record using a form with captcha but when I try to update the data, I got an error regarding to captcha "The verification code is incorrect". How to skip verification on update the data.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use conditional validation, e.g. :

```
['verifyCode', 'captcha', 'when' => function($model) {
    // validate captcha only for new records
    return $model->getIsNewRecord();
}]
```

Read more about [conditional validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation).

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your validation rule :
Try this

```
['verifyCode', 'captcha','captchaAction'=>'/youractionname/default/captcha'],
```

ie : `['verifyCode', 'captcha','captchaAction'=>'/contactus/default/captcha'],`

Or Else

this might be helpful to you

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captchaaction.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found it and worked.

in model function rules put 'on'=>'captchaRequired' .

TQ